# Select a subset of foreign key elements in inlineformset_factory in Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views, django-queryset

I have a model with two foreign keys:

```
class Model1(models.Model):
  model_a = models.ForeignKey(ModelA)
  model_b = models.ForeignKey(ModelB)
  value = models.IntegerField()
```

Then, I create an inline formset class, like so:

```
an_inline_formset = inlineformset_factory(ModelA, Model1, fk_name="model_a")
```

and then instantiate it, like so:

```
a_formset = an_inline_formset(request.POST, instance=model_A_object)
```

Once this formset gets rendered in a template/page, there is ChoiceField associated with the model_b field. The problem I'm having is that the elements in the resulting drop down menu include all of the elements found in ModelB table. I need to select a subset of those based on some criteria from ModelB. At the same time, I need to keep the reference to the instance of model_A_object when instantiating inlineformset_factory and, therefore, I can't just use [this](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/#inline-formsets) example. Any suggestions?

Comment: Just added a generic `django` tag so it would be highlighted for people who aren't following the very specific tags.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need to do is [change the ModelChoiceField's queryset](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/ref/forms/fields/#django.forms.ModelChoiceField.queryset)

The easiest way to do this may be to monkey-patch the formset's form. You should be able to do this right after constructing the formset with:

```
an_inline_formset.form.base_fields['model_b'].queryset = ModelB.objects.filter(whatever=True)
```

Not the prettiest, but it should work.